# What is 'gamma' parameter in OneClassSVM in scikit-learn Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, outliers

I am using OneClassSVM for novelty detection. Default gamma is said to be `1/n_features`, and *n_features* in my case is **250**. Changing gamma by 5 times or reducing by 5 times does not affect the prediction sensitivity significantly. What does gamma exactly represents and how can I effectively use it to tune the model (especially to increase positive predictive value)?

Comment: which kernel did you choose ? check if it is   ‘rbf’, ‘poly’ or ‘sigmoid’?

Comment: I am using the default one : 'rbf'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#kernel-functions

It's a parameter only for for ‘rbf’, ‘poly’ and ‘sigmoid’ kernel.

Also read this http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html#outlier-detection.

There is no such thing as

> positive predictive value

Because it's unsupervised learning. But you can variate your parameters with GridSearchCV, though i don't know which metric you can use for choosing best model from it.

Comment: If I consider all the data corresponding to faults generated in some machine as outliers, can I define PPV as probability of a predicted outlier truly being a FAULT?

Comment: @Sangram Hmm, if you want to minimize number of outliers - maybe you just should minimize number of predicted -1 or +1? I.e. create custom scorer which will count number of predicted outliers on training set.

Look here for custom scorer example http://stackoverflow.com/a/32422921/1030820

Comment: @Sangram, also, you should variate your nu parameter to decrease number of outliers, most probably you will need to decrease it.

Comment: I have tried varying 'nu' parameter and am getting results as expected. Thanks!